# TYPO3 TCA foreign where field = uid

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18

```
'friends' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:friends',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_feuserfriends_domain_model_friend',
        'foreign_match_fields' => [
            'user_from' => '###THIS_UID### '
        ],
        'foreign_table_where' => 'tx_feuserfriends_domain_model_friend.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ',
        'maxitems' => '5000'
    ),
),
```

I extended fe_users. All works, bit this configuration does't works. I need get all items where foreign_table.user_from = current_uid or where foreign_table.user_to. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
'friends' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:friends',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_feuserfriends_domain_model_friend',
        'foreign_field' => 'user_from',
        'symmetric_field' => 'user_to',

        'maxitems' => '5000'
    ),
),
```

solution               'symmetric_field' => 'user_to',